# Android Studio Windows 10 (64)

Tags: android, windows-10

I cannot find an solution to my problem *anywhere* so please forgive me by asking this question here.

I've recently upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10. I'm half-way through the sunshine project and Android Studio WILL not run. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, ran in compatibility mode, everything   all I briefly get is the splash screen and then nothing. No trace in Task Manager. No events logged in Windows event manager. Zip.

And as for Virtualbox hosting a genymotion Nexus 7 vm, don't even get me started.

Can someone please help me ?

Thanks

MM
btw Latest version of java installed.

Comment: We actually not understand your problem. Ideally this is suppose to not possible that the studio not showing the log. Did you resstart the android studios. let try by restrating the studios.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. What does VirtualBox have to do with this? Have you spoken to Google / JetBrains?

Comment: are you facing problem starting android studio? if so post a screenshot of error.

Comment: Initially do not start any emulator using genymotion and close all the application running...just start the Android Studio in as administrator...If you are getting any error then post it in question..if it is lagging then check the memory consumed by it in Task Manager....

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I'll try to answer each one. After upgrading, my normal routine is (prior to starting A studio) to start the genymotion vm of my nexus 7 - this failed, telling me to try it through VB. This failed (problems with network adapter). OK, so I tried to break the problem down by starting AStudio on its own, without an emulator. The Splash screen shows then disappears and that's it. No errors, nothing. Once I get A Studio running I can then concentrate on VB. AS is run in compatibility mode for W7, admin. I'm so close to finishing the sunshine project, any help apprec.thx

Comment: btw A Studio is a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

With Genymotion, what version do you use ?. I upgrade my window from 8.1 to window 10 and my Genymotion alway get error, I uninstalling both VB and Genymotion (completely clear reg file, delete any log file or folder in C:\user\yourPC ) and Install the last version of genymotion without Virtual Box, install last version of Virtual Box then Run your genymotion in compatibility mode "Window 7/8/8.1". But some time Genymotion can crash, Window 10 not support completely Virtualbox.

With AndroidStudio, It work well in Window 10 then I think you not clean remove it.